# Understanding and using Strengthening/Weakening theorems

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In `A Logical Approach to Discrete Math` by Gries p.58, appears this passage.

> Each of the theorems (3.76a)-(3.76e) is called weakening or strengthening , depending on whether it is used to transform the antecedent into the consequent, thus weakening it, or to transform the consequent into the antecedent, thus strengthening it.

[image]

I have two questions:

- What the significance of weakening and strengthening in this context?
- I know how to use theorems that have equals replacing “equals by equals” with Leibniz rule of Inference. But, how can I use theorems that have an implication? Do I need to use modus ponens or use an implication in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > What the significance of weakening and strengthening in this context?

By weakening and strengthening we change the amount of possible outcomes for some proposition. By weakening a proposition we include in general more possibilities for the outcome. By strengthening a proposition we exclude in general more possibilities. We can use the strength or weakness of a proposition to express it's relative strength to another proposition (stronger or weaker).

Suppose we have two propositions $P$ and $Q$. Then if we would say $P$ is stronger than $Q$ it would mean that: in every case $P$ is true, $Q$ is also true.

This can be written as: $P \vDash Q$

Note that in case $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent it means that the "stronger than" works in both directions. So $P \vDash Q$ and $Q \vDash P$.

> > I know how to use theorems that have equals replacing “equals by equals” with Leibniz rule of Inference. But, how can I use theorems that have an implication? Do I need to use modus ponens or use an implication in my reasoning?

> > Edit: I am trying to say, how can I invoke those theorems in a proof ? Suppose I want to "strength" a certain proposition; how can I introduce theorem 3.76 (a)

We can use the properties of the "stronger than" to derive logical connectives between propositions.

1. $P \vDash Q$  and $Q \vDash P$ means that the truth tables are exact the same. Thus we can conclude that $P$ and $Q$ are therefore equivalent.
2. If we only have $P \vDash Q$, then $P \implies Q$ must be a tautology.
3. We can conclude that "stronger" and "weaker" are opposites.

Strengthening is done by decreasing the possible "1" for a proposition. The more it tends to $FALSE$ the stronger it is, with $FALSE$ being the most extreme strongest and $TRUE$ being the weakest.

Note that 3.76(A) as a whole is a tautology since $P \vDash P \lor Q $.

Using the $\lor$ connective that part of a proposition weaker since it creates more possibilities that the truth value will be true. Hence , using the $\land$ will make that part of the proposition stronger since we have less different possibilities that the truth value will be true. This is what you can see in the theorems in (3.76)

In (a) the right part of the implication is weakened by the $\lor$

In (b) the left part of the implication is made stronger by the $\land$

In (c) the left part of the implication is made stronger by the $\land$ and the right part weaker by the $\lor$

In (d) and (e) the connectives $\land$ $\lor$ in each part create more strength or weakness.

In the end it just comes down to the truth tables and that the stronger proposition indicates that the weaker proposition must always have a *1 or true* in the truth table whenever the stronger proposition has a *true or 1*

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to say, how can I invoke those theorems in a proof ? Suppose I want to "strength" a certain proposition; how can I introduce theorem 3.76 (a), for example. Perhaps, I even don't understand how to phrase it as I have little experience with logic.

Comment: Does that make it more clear? If not I would recommend making a truth table for the given proposition and compute the truth values for all parts of the full proposition and then look at the columns in pairs to find the combinations of pairs such that for all "1's" in the first column, the second column also has "1's" in the same rows.

Comment: Thanks. So, If I have a single variable $p$ in a proof, can I replace by $p \vee q$ (weakening it), invoking theorem 3.76 a ?

Comment: No, you cannot replace it since $p$ is not equivalent to ($p \lor q$). Because if $p$ would be false and $q$ be true we have that the first variable is false, but the disjunction is true. But we can derive that $p$ is stronger that the conjunction as whole.Thus from this we can derive that $p$ implies  ($p \lor q$). Depending on what you are proving you can then draw valid conclusions about for example that the proposition in 3.76 must be a tautologie.

Comment: So in short, we can't replace it, but during reasoning by using the definitions and properties we can use inference to conclude that certain things must be true or false.

Comment: Oh, I am starting to get it. So each of the theorems in the picture is a tautology ?

Comment: In general a "theorem" is a (non-self-evident) statement that has been proven to be true. So the result must always be true. So when you are reasoning about something, perhaps more advanced, you can use this theorem to deduct facts about the thing you are reasoning about. And by proofing the theorem yourself using correct (logical) deduction you sort of show to yourself that you understand the theorem. So you understand what the theorem means, but also the whole process of logical steps behind it.

Comment: Further conversation is moved to chat. I think this covers everything related to your questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101533/discussion-between-joshuarms-and-f-zer).

Answer (score 3):

See footnote 10 (page 58) :

> Suppose $P \to Q$. We say that $P$ is *stronger than* $Q$ because $Q$ is *true* in more (or at least the same) states that $P$.

This means (see the truth table for $P \to Q$) that when $P$ is TRUE, also $Q$ must be.

Here "stronger" in the sense that it "exclude more possibilities" : "the strongest formula is *false*".

The theorems of (3.76) are obtained from $p \to p$ either by replacing a "weaker" formula into the consequent : $p \vDash (p \lor q)$, and this is *weakening*, or by replacing a "stronger" formula in the antecedent : $(p \land q) \vDash p$, and this is *strengthening*.

And from them we get $(p \land q) \to (p \lor q)$ from the first one by *strengthening* or from the second one by *weakening*.

---

The fact that $p \vDash p \lor q$ must be checked with truth-table.

But the issue is : how to prove $p \to (p \lor q)$ with Gries' proof system ?

We can use the hint of **Ex.60**, page 65 and follow the strategy explained in the proof of the theorems of **Ch.3**.

Note that the law we want to prove is not an equivalence; in Gries' system, to prove that a formula $\varphi$ is theorem (i.e. a *tautology*) amounts to prove : $\varphi \equiv \top$ [using $\top$ for $\text {true}$].

We start with (3.43b) **Absorption** [page 52]: it is a theorem; thus it is equivalent to $\top$ :

> $p \land (p \lor q) \equiv p$.

Then we use (3.60) **Definition of implication** [page 56] : $(p \to q) \equiv ((p \land q) \equiv p)$.

Replacing $q$ with $p \lor q$ in it we get, by **Substitution** rule [page 41] : $p \to (p \lor q) \equiv (p \land (p \lor q)) \equiv p$.

Thus, by transitivity of $\equiv$ :

> > $\top \equiv p \to (p \lor q)$.

Comment: Thank you. How can you go from $p \rightarrow p$ to $p \models p \vee q$. Perhaps, I am missing a very basic point. What would be a real world usage? Is it for proving a theorem?

Comment: This issue got me thinking...the whole point of an implication is that I can leverage it only in “one way” ?

Comment: The point of a implication is that: would the left side of the implication be true, then the right side must also be true. Otherwise it would mean that the implication is incorrect. But the value of right-side of the implication itself is not dependent of that of the left hand side. So from a true left side we can derive that the right side must hold. But when the left side is false, we don't really care about value of the right hand side, BUT the implication still holds. And you are correct about the "one way". From the right side, we cannot derive facts about the left side. For exmaple:

Comment: Suppose $P$ would be the statement "Peter loves all movies" and $Q$ would be "Peter loves the movie Star Wars". Then $P \implies Q$. Since Peter loves ALL movies he must also like Star Wars. But would we only know that Peter loves the movie Star Wars, we can't de derive whether or not he loves all movies.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MauroALLEGRANZA. Could you explain the use of Symmetry in the last step?

Comment: @F.Zer - it is simply : from $A \equiv B$ to $B \equiv A$, in order to match with the previous step.

Comment: But RHS disappeared in between those steps; how did you used that rule?\begin{equation}
p \to (p \lor q) \equiv (p \land (p \lor q)) \equiv p \\
p \to (p \lor q)
\end{equation}

Comment: @F.Zer - it is only a chian of equivalences: if $A \equiv B$ and $B \equiv C$, then $A \equiv C$. As said in my answer, the implicit assumption is that the first formula is equiv to TRUE; thus, using the "chain", also the last one is, i.e. is a theorem.

Comment: Now I got it. A theorem is equivalent to True. You proved that law was equivalent to a theorem, so by transitivity, it is is equivalent to true. Thank you !